# Prove that {A ⇒ ¬C, ¬A ⇒ B} ⊢ C ⇒ B using only Modus Ponens, the typical theorem (A → ¬C) → (C → ¬A) and 3 axioms.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

I have an exercise where I have to prove the given sentence
{A ⇒ ¬C, ¬A ⇒ B} ⊢ C ⇒ B using only Modus Ponens, the typical theorem (A → ¬C) → (C → ¬A)
and the following three axioms:

1. A→(B→A)
2. (A→(B→C))→((A→B)→(A→C))
3. (¬A→¬B)→((¬A→B)→A)

what I've done so far is

1. A ⇒ ¬C   Premise
2. (A → ¬C) → (C → ¬A)   from the Typical Theorem
3. (C → ¬A)  M.P 1,2
4. ¬A ⇒ B  Premise
   ...

However I'm getting a bit confused on what substitutions to do given the 3 axioms in order proceed.

Any ideas anyone?
Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an intermediate result (sometimes called [Hypothetical Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Propositional_logic)):

> *Lemma* : $A \rightarrow B, B \rightarrow C \vdash A \rightarrow C$

(1) $A \rightarrow B$ --- assumed

(2) $B \rightarrow C$ --- assumed

(3) $\vdash (B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C))$ --- Ax1

(4) $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$ --- from (2) and (3) by *Modus Ponens*

(5) $\vdash [A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)] \rightarrow [(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)]$ --- Ax2

(6) $(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$ --- from (4) and (5) by *Modus Ponens*

> (7) $A \rightarrow C$ --- from (1) and (6) by *MP*.

Now the main result:

(1) $A \to ¬C$ --- premise

(2) $¬A \to B$ --- premise

(3) $C \to \lnot A$ --- from (1) and the *Typical Theorem* by *MP*

> (4) $C \to B$ --- from (3), (1) and *Lemma*.